# When using hyperedger with virtualbox, can i have some instances at one network?

Tags: virtualbox, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am a beginner in a block chain. So there are many questions.
When configuring the hyperledger network, create multiple ubuntu instances using virtualbox on one pc. Can the peers within each instance be connected in a single block-chain network?

Thanks in advance for your availability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in identifying that the Peers need to communicate with each other. In the default Development Fabric, all the docker containers are running on a single machine and the network addressing/routing is managed by Docker Compose.  If you split your fabric to separate Virtualbox Ubuntu instances, you will have to understand and manage the network addressing/routing.  This is a Docker and networking issue, not really a Fabric or Composer issue.  You may find that Kubernetes is the most helpful way forward for you or Docker Swarm.

Answer (score 0):

For that, you have to create your fabric network and then add everyone to the network. You need to configure each and every peer in the channel config using configtxgen tool.